Left-aligned and centered text on same line (not equations) when text is too long and overprints elements
In a previous post, I was given an answer which mostly works very well.
\NewDocumentCommand{\datefeast}{mm}{%
  \par
  \noindent
  \makebox[0pt][l]{#1.}%
  \makebox[\textwidth]{\Large #2.}%
  }

However, I finally ran into the one drawback: the text is now long enough to over-print the number. See this.  I'm planning on abbreviating where possible, but there aren't really conventional abbreviations in this case, not for "Sacrorum Stigmatum" at least.
I need it to do this, preferably with the first line longer than the second as shown.

Something like this?

The macro \newdatefeast takes three arguments: The event's number, the single widest line in the event announcement, and the full text of the event announcement. Observe that you are in charge of setting the font size and, if needed, font shape for each line of the event text. Note also that there's some overlap between the contents of the 2nd and 3rd argument of the macro, as I didn't wish to impose the assumption that the first line is necessarily the longest one.
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,calc}
\setmainfont{EB Garamond}[Ligatures={Common,Rare}]

\newcommand\newdatefeast[3]{%
   \par\noindent #1\hspace{3mm}%
   \parbox[t]{\widthof{#2}}{\centering #3}}

\begin{document}

\newdatefeast{7}{\Large Impressionis Sacrorum Stigmatum}
   {{\Large Impressionis Sacrorum Stigmatum}

    {\large in corpore S. Francisci Confessoris.}
   
    {\itshape\footnotesize De Communi Confessoris non Pontificis, pr\ae ter sequentia.}}
 
\end{document}


Thanks for the help. It got me thinking about what I needed. However, it wasn't centered as in the original version, and it was as simple as adding \hfill\makebox[\textwidth]{\large #3.}.
